# WPF - Pass data between Viewmodels

Tags: c#

I have a view model and field and I want to send field another view model. I cant use object initialize because the constructor executions first and this field is null. I need this field in the constructor. I tried constructor parameter but that didn't work I get a error;

```
'ProductDetailViewModel' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TVm' in the generic type or method 'BasePage<TVm>'
```

P.S: sorry for my English :|

My Base Page:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The base page for all pages to gain base functionality
/// </summary>
public class BasePage : UserControl
{
    #region Private Member

    /// <summary>
    /// The View Model associated with this page
    /// </summary>
    private object mViewModel;

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The animation the play when the page is first loaded
    /// </summary>
    public PageAnimation PageLoadAnimation { get; set; } = PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeInFromRight;

    /// <summary>
    /// The animation the play when the page is unloaded
    /// </summary>
    public PageAnimation PageUnloadAnimation { get; set; } = PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeOutToLeft;

    /// <summary>
    /// The time any slide animation takes to complete
    /// </summary>
    public float SlideSeconds { get; set; } = 0.4f;

    /// <summary>
    /// A flag to indicate if this page should animate out on load.
    /// Useful for when we are moving the page to another frame
    /// </summary>
    public bool ShouldAnimateOut { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The View Model associated with this page
    /// </summary>
    public object ViewModelObject
    {
        get => mViewModel;
        set
        {
            // If nothing has changed, return
            if (mViewModel == value)
                return;

            // Update the value
            mViewModel = value;

            // Fire the view model changed method
            OnViewModelChanged();

            // Set the data context for this page
            DataContext = mViewModel;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public BasePage()
    {
        // Don't bother animating in design time
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            return;

        // If we are animating in, hide to begin with
        if (PageLoadAnimation != PageAnimation.None)
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        // Listen out for the page loading
        Loaded += BasePage_LoadedAsync;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Animation Load / Unload

    /// <summary>
    /// Once the page is loaded, perform any required animation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private async void BasePage_LoadedAsync(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If we are setup to animate out on load
        if (ShouldAnimateOut)
            // Animate out the page
            await AnimateOutAsync();
        // Otherwise...
        else
            // Animate the page in
            await AnimateInAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Animates the page in
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task AnimateInAsync()
    {
        // Make sure we have something to do
        if (PageLoadAnimation == PageAnimation.None)
            return;

        switch (PageLoadAnimation)
        {
            case PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeInFromRight:

                // Start the animation
                await this.SlideAndFadeInAsync(AnimationSlideInDirection.Right, false, SlideSeconds,
                    size: (int)Application.Current.MainWindow.Width);

                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Animates the page out
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task AnimateOutAsync()
    {
        // Make sure we have something to do
        if (PageUnloadAnimation == PageAnimation.None)
            return;

        switch (PageUnloadAnimation)
        {
            case PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeOutToLeft:

                // Start the animation
                await this.SlideAndFadeOutAsync(AnimationSlideInDirection.Left, SlideSeconds);

                break;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Fired when the view model changes
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnViewModelChanged()
    {
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A base page with added ViewModel support
/// </summary>
public class BasePage<TVm> : BasePage
    where TVm : BaseViewModel, new()
{
    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The view model associated with this page
    /// </summary>
    public TVm ViewModel
    {
        get => (TVm)ViewModelObject;
        set => ViewModelObject = value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public BasePage() : base()
    {
        // If in design time mode...
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            // Just use a new instance of the VM
            ViewModel = new TVm();
        else
            // Create a default view model
            ViewModel = Framework.Service<TVm>() ?? new TVm();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor with specific view model
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="specificViewModel">The specific view model to use, if any</param>
    public BasePage(TVm specificViewModel = null) : base()
    {
        // Set specific view model
        if (specificViewModel != null)
            ViewModel = specificViewModel;
        else
        {
            // If in design time mode...
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
                // Just use a new instance of the VM
                ViewModel = new TVm();
            else
            {
                // Create a default view model
                ViewModel = Framework.Service<TVm>() ?? new TVm();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My Base View Model:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A base view model that fires Property Changed events as needed
    /// </summary>
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Protected Members

        /// <summary>
        /// A global lock for property checks so prevent locking on different instances of expressions.
        /// Considering how fast this check will always be it isn't an issue to globally lock all callers.
        /// </summary>
        protected object mPropertyValueCheckLock = new object();

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// The event that is fired when any child property changes its value
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this to fire a <see cref="PropertyChanged"/> event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        #region Command Helpers

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs a command if the updating flag is not set.
        /// If the flag is true (indicating the function is already running) then the action is not run.
        /// If the flag is false (indicating no running function) then the action is run.
        /// Once the action is finished if it was run, then the flag is reset to false
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="updatingFlag">The boolean property flag defining if the command is already running</param>
        /// <param name="action">The action to run if the command is not already running</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected async Task RunCommandAsync(Expression<Func<bool>> updatingFlag, Func<Task> action)
        {
            // Lock to ensure single access to check
            lock (mPropertyValueCheckLock)
            {
                // Check if the flag property is true (meaning the function is already running)
                if (updatingFlag.GetPropertyValue())
                    return;

                // Set the property flag to true to indicate we are running
                updatingFlag.SetPropertyValue(true);
            }

            try
            {
                // Run the passed in action
                await action();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Set the property flag back to false now it's finished
                updatingFlag.SetPropertyValue(false);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs a command if the updating flag is not set.
        /// If the flag is true (indicating the function is already running) then the action is not run.
        /// If the flag is false (indicating no running function) then the action is run.
        /// Once the action is finished if it was run, then the flag is reset to false
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="updatingFlag">The boolean property flag defining if the command is already running</param>
        /// <param name="action">The action to run if the command is not already running</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type the action returns</typeparam>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected async Task<T> RunCommandAsync<T>(Expression<Func<bool>> updatingFlag, Func<Task<T>> action, T defaultValue = default(T))
        {
            // Lock to ensure single access to check
            lock (mPropertyValueCheckLock)
            {
                // Check if the flag property is true (meaning the function is already running)
                if (updatingFlag.GetPropertyValue())
                    return defaultValue;

                // Set the property flag to true to indicate we are running
                updatingFlag.SetPropertyValue(true);
            }

            try
            {
                // Run the passed in action
                return await action();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Set the property flag back to false now it's finished
                updatingFlag.SetPropertyValue(false);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

View Model Constructor:
[View Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeBpD.png)

Comment: Highly recommend this video for View Model communication https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o62iFhXkWS4

Comment: @Squirrel.98 Unfortunately, I didn't do what I was looking for with this video :(